# How do I get a Guild instance in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to get a particular guild with discord.py.
The reason I want to do that is so I can get some roles from this guild and assign them to constant variables so that I can have access to these roles whenever I want.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='~')

MAIN_GUILD = bot.get_guild(* guild ID *)
UNMUTED = discord.utils.get(MAIN_GUILD.roles, name = 'Unmuted')
DEAFENED = discord.utils.get(MAIN_GUILD.roles, name = 'Undeafened')
```

When I run the program it says that `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'` so the `MAIN_GUILD = bot.get_guild(* guild ID *)` command isn't working, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: you simply have to wait till the bot is done loading the cache

Comment: You have to wait till the discord gateway is done sending all the data (it's obvious it's not gonna send everything in 10ms), one way would be using the `on_ready` event.

Comment: How do I do that? Because the error occurs right when I run the program and I think it terminates it. @ŁukaszKwieciński

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the comments said, just put the code inside an `on_ready` event:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='~')
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    MAIN_GUILD = bot.get_guild(* guild ID *)
    UNMUTED = discord.utils.get(MAIN_GUILD.roles, name = 'Unmuted')
    DEAFENED = discord.utils.get(MAIN_GUILD.roles, name = 'Undeafened')
```

but if you want to used the variables later on other commands/events, then you would need to set the variables as global variables, for example:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='~')
id = *guild Id*
global roles

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    global roles
    MAIN_GUILD=client.get_guild(id)
    roles = MAIN_GUILD.roles

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def print_roles():
    global roles
    for x in roles:
        print(x)
```